# SVG's tabIndex is not working in IE and React

Tags: html, reactjs, internet-explorer, svg

The **tabIndex** for an **svg** text element doesn't work in IE11 and Edge when using react components.

I'm expecting to execute a *keypress* event for a text element inside an svg using a React component. This seems to work fine in chrome and FF, but the it fails for IE11 and Edge.

For some reason, the *tabIndex* attribute is not being handled in IE when set in the react's jsx, causing the svg's text to have no focus to do a keypress.

```
<html>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
class Greeting extends React.Component {

    doSomething() {
        alert("Keypress captured");
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <svg viewBox="0 -20 800 300">
                <text fill="#273039" fontSize="25" width="150" tabIndex="0" onKeyPress={this.doSomething}>
                    <tspan>Type something here!</tspan>
                </text>
            </svg>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <Greeting />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
</html>
```

Here is an example to try in chrome and IE:
https://jsfiddle.net/pabloherre/nou8rc4e

Do you guys have any workaround for this? or seems to be a bug?

Comment: tabindex is part of SVG 2. IE11 only supports SVG 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `focusable="true"` in the `<text>` tag.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
        class Greeting extends React.Component {

        doSomething() {
        alert("Keypress captured");
        }

        render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <svg viewBox="0 -20 800 300">
                    <text fill="#273039" fontSize="25" width="150" tabIndex="0" focusable="true" onKeyPress={this.doSomething}>
                        <tspan>Type something here!</tspan>
                    </text>
            </svg>
        </div>
        );
        }
        }
        ReactDOM.render(
        <Greeting />,
        document.getElementById('root')
        );
    </script>
```